# why isnt my .innerHTML working, javascript game

Tags: javascript, html

i swear i can do this an it must just be a machine error. I have the same thing working in over programs but within a method. I was simply coping someone elses working code. I cant update the score from 0 to 1. Can anyone take a look? must be the tiniest logic error ever or something. Yes im calling my css and js. Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Clicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="game.js"></script>

    <h1>CLICKER</h1>
    <p id="score">Score: 0</p>
    <img id="algae" src="/images/algaepng.png" alt="Image">
    
</body>
</html>
```

FROM GAME.JS

```
let score = 0;
score = score +1;
document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
```

Comment: Use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: And add `defer` to your `<script>` element's attributes so it won't load (and run) until `DOMContentLoaded`, otherwise `getElementById('score')` will return `null`.

Comment: But why would you first set `score` to zero, when in the very next statement you make it one? Why even the variable, when it is no more varying after it is 1? Why do you display "clicker"? Is there anything to click? Shouldn't you then respond to a click event?

Comment: just place your js script just before your closing body tag

Comment: you are looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/usiel000/dnv2hpau/3/

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript code is executed before the HTML code 
Solution 1: Declare the script in the head with the word defer

```js
let score = 0;
score = score + 1;
document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Clicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="game.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>CLICKER</h1>
    <p id="score">Score: 0</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Solution 2: declare your javascript at the end of the body

```js
let score = 0;
score = score + 1;
document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Clicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>CLICKER</h1>
    <p id="score">Score: 0</p>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, big help. There are so many little things like that you take a life to figure out. Cheers for helping a dummy